# 'UIButton.titleLabel?.text' doesn't work as expected/doesn't overwrite string

Tags: swift, uibutton

My problem is as follows:

```
var player = 2

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

func CheckWin() -> Bool
{
    if button1.titleLabel?.text == button2.titleLabel?.text && button2.titleLabel?.text == button3.titleLabel?.text && button1.titleLabel?.text != nil
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == nil
    {
        if player%2==0
        {
            sender.setTitle("X", for: UIControlState.normal)
            player += 1
            turn += 1
            label.text = "Player 'O' Turn"
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setTitle("O", for: UIControlState.normal)
            player += 1
            turn += 1
            label.text = "Player 'X' Turn"
        }
    }
    if CheckWin()
    {
        resetButtons()
    }
}

func resetButtons() {

    button1.titleLabel?.text = nil
    button2.titleLabel?.text = nil
    button3.titleLabel?.text = nil
}
```

I'm trying to reset the Button's-text to nil (empty/no text), to restart the Game. It all works fine but when it comes to the "func resetButtons()"-Method it puts the visible text from the buttons to nil but somehow the the text is still "X" or "O".

I've tried to use button1.setTitle(nil) and other different writings in the resetButtons()-Method but it doesn't change a thing. I also tried changing Settings from .System to Custom - didn't work either.
Everytime I debug it and go the breakpoint it shows that still after "resetButton()" should have changed the Buttontext it still is "X" or "O", but visibly the button is empty as it should be... it is really weird.

I figured out that the problem might be, that when I set the Button-text at first, it's "sender.titleLabel?.text" and not "button1.titleLabel?.text". Could that really be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the appearance is correct, it's possible that the debugger is lying to you.  It wouldn't be the first time that has happened to someone.

Comment: it is hard to explain. It puts the Buttons.Text to (EMPTY) as I want. But when I click again on a Button, there is already a value stored. It shows me an "X" or an "O" and it doesn't store the text on the Button anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained earlier, don't use nil for an empty string. The following works for me. Also it turns out (after scanning the docs) that `UIButton.titleLabel` is read only. Its own properties are read/write but the `titleLabel` itself is read only, hence why you have to use `setTitle` and why using `sender.titleLabel?.text` doesn't work in the `if` statement. Try the following.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resetButtons()
}

func CheckWin() -> Bool
{
    if button1.title(for: .normal) == button2.title(for: .normal) && button2.title(for: .normal) == button3.title(for: .normal) && button1.title(for: .normal) != ""
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if sender.title(for: .normal) == ""
    {
        if player%2==0
        {
            sender.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
            player += 1
            turn += 1
            label.text = "Player 'O' Turn"
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
            player += 1
            turn += 1
            label.text = "Player 'X' Turn"
        }
    }
    if CheckWin()
    {
        resetButtons()
    }
}

func resetButtons() {

    button1.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button2.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button3.setTitle("", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as mine.

Comment: @kkakkurt, sorry yes. Caught that as I posted it. Have modified my answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT FINALLY WORKED! Both of you! Thank you so much! You really made my day!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept one of the answers. Doesn't matter which - you're question helped me sort things out too.

Comment: @Magnas There you go! Thanks again, glad to hear it also helped you a little. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use empty strings for it:

```
func resetButtons() {
    button1.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button2.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button3.setTitle("", for: .normal)
}
```

And change your if control like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == ""  //Changed control mechanism
    {
        if player%2==0
        {
            sender.setTitle("X", for: UIControlState.normal)
            player += 1
            turn += 1
            label.text = "Player 'O' Turn"
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setTitle("O", for: UIControlState.normal)
            player += 1
            turn += 1
            label.text = "Player 'X' Turn"
        }
    }
    if CheckWin()
    {
        resetButtons()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before but this resets the Button as i would like but it wont let me click on a button again...

Comment: Because you are controlling button texts if they are nil or not. If you control them with _sender.titleLabel?.text == ""_ it won't give errors anymore. I've updated the answer.